# No se actualizan los datos en mi BD

Tags: php, mysql

Intento actualizar mis datos marcando varios checkbox y me dice que la inserción se realizo pero cuando veo mi base de datos no se a actualizado , aquí esta el extracto de mi código

```
    <div class="table-responsive">
    <form action="checkruta.php" method="post" >
   <table class="table table-striped table-hover">
    <tr>
               <th>Folio </th>
      <th>Nombre</th>
      <th>Fecha solicitud</th>
      <th>Solicitud</th>
      <th>Estado</th>
      <th>Fecha Reporte</th>
      <th>Seleccionar Ruta</th>
    </tr>
    <?php
    if($filter){
      $sql = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM contribuyente WHERE estado='$filter'  ORDER BY id ASC");
    }else{
      $sql = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM contribuyente ORDER BY id ASC");
    }
    if(mysqli_num_rows($sql) == 0){
      echo '<tr><td colspan="8">No hay datos.</td></tr>';
    }else{
      $no = 1;
      while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sql)){
        echo '
        <tr>
          <td>'.$row['id'].'</td>
          <td><a href="profile.php?nik='.$row['nombre'].'"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user" aria-hidden="true"></span> '.$row['nombre'].'</a></td>
                        <td>'.$row['fecha'].'</td>
                        <td>'.$row['mensaje'].'</td>
                         <td>'.$row['estado'].'</td>
                         <td>'.$row['fecha_rec'].'</td>
        <td> <input type="checkbox" name="id[]" value=<?php echo $row["id"]; ?></td>

          <td>';
          if($row['estado'] == 'Resuelto'){
            echo '<span class="label label-success">Resuelto</span>';
          }
                        else if ($row['estado'] == 'Pendiente' ){
            echo '<span class="label label-info">Pendiente</span>';
          }
                        else if ($row['estado'] == 'Rechazado' ){
            echo '<span class="label label-warning">Rechazado</span>';
          }
        echo '
          </td>


        </tr>
        ';
        $no++;
      }
    }
    ?>
  </table>
  <input type="submit" name="autorizados" value="Autorizar seleccionados" />
   </div>
   </div>
   </div>
```

y aqui esta mi codigo que actualiza

```
  <?php 

  if (isset($_POST['autorizados'])) { 

//Conexión Mysql.
  $db_host="localhost";
  $db_user="root";
  $db_password= "";
  $db_name="bdpagina";
  $db_connection = mysqli_connect($db_host, $db_user, $db_password, $db_name);


  $id = $_POST['id'];  
  $count = count($id);
  $status = 'AUTORIZADA';

   for ($i=0; $i < $count; $i++) {


    mysqli_query($db_connection,"UPDATE contribuyente SET ruta='$status'
    WHERE id='$id[$i]' LIMIT 1");

}

mysqli_close($db_connection);    
echo "Se actualizo correctamente";     
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Te dice que se actualizo correctamente porque `echo "Se actualizo correctamente"` siempre se va a imprimir de la forma en la que tienes planteado tu código.

Para comprobar si la query se ha completado correctamente te recomiendo almacenarla en una variable y luego comprobarla con un `if`.

```
$result=mysqli_query($db_connection,"UPDATE contribuyente SET ruta='$status'
WHERE id='$id[$i]' LIMIT 1");

if($result){
 $message = "Consulta realizada.";
} else {
 $message = "Se ha producido un error.";
}

mysqli_close($db_connection);    
echo $message;
```

Si quieres comprobar si la conexión a la base de datos ha fallado puedes usar:

```
if ($db_connection->connect_error) {
  die("Error de conexión: " . $db_connection->connect_error);
}
```

Comment: Hola, Probe con el codigo y me dice consulta realizada pero aun así no me actualiza la base de datos

Comment: Podría ser que el `UPDATE` esté funcionando pero que no esté afectando a ninguna fila, añade una comprobación después de tu query: `echo "Num. filas afectadas: ".$db_connection->affected_rows`